# ref return usage details

Tags: c#, return, ref

```cs
public ref string FindAuthor(int number, string[] names)
{
    if (names.Length > 0)
        return ref names[number];   
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException($"{nameof(number)} not found.");
}
```

```cs
//main method
string[] authors = { "Mahesh Chand", "Mike Gold", "Dave McCarter", 
                "Allen O'neill", "Raj Kumar" };

//first variation
string author4 = new Program().FindAuthor(3, authors);
Console.WriteLine("Original author:{0}", author4);
author4 = "Chris Sells";
Console.WriteLine("Replaced author:{0}", authors[3]);

//secondvariation
ref string author4 = ref new Program().FindAuthor(3, authors);
Console.WriteLine("Original author:{0}", author4);
author4 = "Chris Sells";
Console.WriteLine("Replaced author:{0}", authors[3]);
```

So the `FindAuthor` returns by reference and when I capture that in `ref string author4` and then modify it, the `authors` array changes *as expected*.

But when I say `string author4` and then modify the `author4` then the `authors` does not change but it kind of does not make sense to me since the `FindAiythor` method always returns by reference so shouldn't `author4` always change *the reference*?

Could you please tell me what happens here (under the hood maybe)?

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#reference-return-values) says: *In order for the caller to modify the object's state, the reference return value must be stored to a variable that is explicitly defined as a [ref local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-locals)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `string author4 = {expr}` instead of `ref string author4 = ref {expr}`, the method returns a reference to the string-reference, and the compiler immediately *de-references that*, storing just the string-reference (not the reference to the string-reference) in the local. At that point: all changes to `author4` are just changing the local variable, hence no update to `authors`. With the full `ref` version, the assignment to `author4` is an indirect write; the *value* of the local is never changed; instead the value is used to determine where to do the actual write.

In reality, this seems like an unusual choice for a `ref` return.

Comment: Thank you Marc. Could you please tell why do yo think that "In reality, this seems like an unusual choice for a ref return." ?

Comment: @EricMovsessian `ref` return is inherently an *incredibly* niche feature; I honestly don't expect most devs will *ever* need to use it - it is *incredibly* useful, but generally in some *very specific* scenarios - often involving fat structs, perhaps in unmanaged layouts or discriminated unions - things like that. I don't see any reason to use it here - normally I might say "return the index", but in reality: `number` *is* the index, and everything here is just unnecessary *anyway*... I guess I'm saying `ref`-return is something we should be able to say why we're using it, and here... I can't